# make: Nothing to be done for `STAR'

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to test [rna-star](http://code.google.com/p/rna-star/) code. I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine.I have downloaded all the packages necessary:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install g++
>
> sudo apt-get install make

But in the installation step I have problem running `make` command on STAR executable file.on the installation manual I see it says:

> Unzip/tar STAR_x.x.x.tgz file into a directory of your choice <
>   STARsource >, cd < STARsource > and run make. The source code will be
>   compiled and the STAR executable will be generated.

when I run 'make STAR' it says:

> make: Nothing to be done for `STAR'.

any suggestion?

Comment: Does it tell you to run `make STAR`?

Comment: when I run make without parameter it says: 'make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. 'It seems that there is no make file but why it said run make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that the "STAR" target does not exist. In a makefile, you define targets (implicit or explicit) and make takes care of building in the correct orders the dependencies for your target.

You should read documentation on this project or glance at the makefile : it's likely you need to run "make" without parameters (which is stated in your documentation excerpt), something like :

```
tar zxvf star...tgz
cd star...
make
```

Comment: thank you. but when I run make without parameter it says: 'make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
''It seems that there is no make file but why it said run make?

Comment: you should check that you're in the correct folder : once you've extracted the tgz, you should have a Makefile file in your folder. Basically, the error message tells you that it found no file defining the rules.

Comment: Quick look indicates that `STAR` is the correct target.

Comment: but STAR is not a make file.

Comment: I have downloaded a wrong Archive. the correct one is ( STAR 2.3.0e source) which contains make-file in it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into the same problem.

Apparently the following solved it:

Redirect to source map: `cd STAR-2.5.3a/source`

The `Makefile` is in this location, after this just enter the command `make`.

It should start running. If you work in a cluster do not forget to edit your shell configuration before using;

```
export PATH=$HOME/STAR-2.5.3a/source:$PATH
```